# C# compile-time type-conversion error

Tags: c#

I'm getting a compile-time type conversion error with this code... dunno if i'm just tired, but I can't figure out what I need to change in the class to fix this. Any pointers would be awesome, thanks

> The error is: "error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `csharpfinal.Packaging<string>`  to `csharpfinal.IGetValue<object>`.  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

```
    interface ISetValue<T>
    {
         void SetData(T data);
    }

    interface IGetValue<T>
    {
         T GetData();
    }

    class Packaging<T> : ISetValue<T>, IGetValue<T>
    {
     private T storedData;
     void ISetValue<T>.SetData(T data)
     {
         this.storedData = data;
     }
     T IGetValue<T>.GetData()
     {
     return this.storedData;
     }
    }

    class Program
    {        
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
            Packaging<string> stringPackage = new Packaging<string>();
            ISetValue<string> setStringValue = stringPackage;
            setStringValue.SetData("Sample string");
            // the line below causes a compile-time error
            IGetValue<object> getObjectValue = stringPackage;

     Console.WriteLine("{0}", getObjectValue.GetData());
     }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `IGetValue<string> getObjectValue = stringPackage;`

Comment: Does my code is wrong ?

Comment: Was trying to do it without changing <object>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify this code

```
interface ISetValue<T>
{
     void SetData(T data);
}

interface IGetValue<T>
{
     T GetData();
}
```

to

```
interface ISetValue<in T>
{
    void SetData(T data);
}

interface IGetValue<out T>
{
    T GetData();
}
```

> For generic type parameters, the out keyword specifies that the type
> parameter is covariant. You can use the out keyword in generic
> interfaces and delegates.
>
> Covariance enables you to use a more derived
> type than that specified by the generic parameter. This allows for
> implicit conversion of classes that implement variant interfaces and
> implicit conversion of delegate types. Covariance and contravariance
> are supported for reference types, but they are not supported for
> value types.

Comment: Should that not be `ISetValue<in T>` ?

Comment: my bad, just copy pasted it from IGetValue :D, thanks

Comment: Hey, I am not sure, that's why I asked ;p

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ISetValue<in T>
    {
        void SetData(T data);
    }

    interface IGetValue<out T>
    {
        T GetData();
    }

    class Packaging<T> : ISetValue<T>, IGetValue<T>
    {
        private T storedData;
        void ISetValue<T>.SetData(T data)
        {
            this.storedData = data;
        }
        T IGetValue<T>.GetData()
        {
            return this.storedData;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Packaging<string> stringPackage = new Packaging<string>();
            ISetValue<string> setStringValue = stringPackage;
            setStringValue.SetData("Sample string");
            // the line below causes a compile-time error
            IGetValue<object> getObjectValue = stringPackage;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", getObjectValue.GetData());
        }
    }
```

more info  :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Packaging<string> stringPackage = new Packaging<string>();
```

^ generic type is `string`

```
IGetValue<object> getObjectValue = stringPackage;
```

but you are trying to cast an `object` generic to a `string` generic, that's why you get the compile-time error.

You can change the generic type of your object initialization to `object` to fix it:

```
Packaging<object> stringPackage = new Packaging<object>();
ISetValue<object> setStringValue = stringPackage;
```

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do it without changing <object>, should have been more clear. Thank though

Answer (score 0):

```
IGetValue<object>
```

Should this be

```
IGetValue<string>
```